# Proof of Theorem 2.2 p.353 Massey

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, compactness, homology-cohomology, orientation

> Theorem: Let $M$ be an $n-$manifold with orientation $\mu$. Then for
> each compact $K \subset M$ there exists a unique class $\mu_K \in
>  H_n(M,M-K)$ such that $$\rho_x(\mu_K) = \mu_x$$ for each $x \in K$.

The uniqueness is not a problem. I don't understand the existence, in particular the "uniformity" over $K$.

My question regards the case of $K \subset U$ where $U$ is open homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$, which should the equivalent of the non-treated case of Massey, citing: *"Obviously if the compact is contained in a sufficiently small neighborhood of some point, the continuity condition of $\mu$ assures us the existence of $\mu_K$"*.

I tried the following: take a disk $D_R^n$ big enough such that $K \subset D_R^n$ and consider the commutative diagram

$$\begin{array}{cc}
\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\mathbb{Z} = H_n(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n \setminus D_R^n) \\
\\
\varphi \downarrow & \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\searrow \,{\simeq} \\
\\
\,\,\,\,\,\,H_n(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n \setminus K) & \xrightarrow{\rho_x}  & \mathbb{Z} = H_n(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n \setminus \left\lbrace x\right\rbrace)
\end{array}$$

Then we can take $\mu$ generator of $H_n(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n \setminus D_R^n)$ that under the isomorphism on the right(given by excision) goes to $\mu_x$. This allow to define $\mu_K := \varphi(\mu)$, in this way clearly $\rho_x(\mu_K) = \mu_x$.

This proves the assertion only for the particular $x$ chosen, and not for all $x \in K$, so my proof is stuck here. I don't know that if in order to prove the thesis for all $x \in K$ I should use the following observation :

If we take $x,y \in M$ that lay in the same ball $D^n \subset M$ then we have

$$ \mathbb{Z} = H_n(M,M- \left\lbrace x \right\rbrace) \leftarrow \mathbb{Z} = H_n(M,M- D) \rightarrow H_n(M,M- \left\lbrace y \right\rbrace)$$

And the map are isomorphism, so we have a canonical isomorphism between $H_n(M,M- \left\lbrace x \right\rbrace)$ and $H_n(M,M- \left\lbrace y \right\rbrace)$.

Any help to finish my proof or any other proof would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say $M=\mathbb R^n\newcommand\R{\mathbb R}\newcommand\sm\setminus$, and fix a compact subset $K\subset\mathbb R^n$. For each $x\in K$, there exists a small open $U_x$ (edit: say, $U_x$ is literally an open ball)  around $x$ and a generator $\mu_{U_x}\in H_n(\R^n,\R^n\setminus U_x)$ so that $\mu_{U_x}$ maps to the chosen generators $\mu_y\in H_n(\R^n,\R^n\sm\{y\})$ for all $y\in U_x$.

Since $K$ is compact, finitely many such $U_x$'s will do, so let $U_1,\dots,U_N$ be a finite open cover of $K$ with generators $\mu_i\in H_n(\R^n,\R^n\sm U_i)$ mapping to the preferred generators in $H_n(\R^n,\R^n\sm\{x\})$ for all $x\in K$. We want to do some induction shortly, but let's first set up a bit of notation. For any $k\in\{2,3,\dots,N\}$, let
$$V_k:=\bigcup_{i=1}^kU_i\text{ and }W_k:=U_k\cap V_{k-1}=\bigcup_{i=1}^{k-1}(U_k\cap U_i).$$
Then, relative Mayer-Vietoris gives us an exact sequence
$$H_n(\R^n,\R^n\sm V_k)\to H_n(\R^n,\R^n\sm V_{k-1})\oplus H_n(\R^n,\R^n\sm U_k)\to H_n(\R^n,W_k)$$
where the first map is what you expect and the second map is $(a,b)\mapsto a-b$. Inductively assume that we have some generator $\nu_{k-1}\in H_n(\R^n,\R^n\sm V_{k-1})$ so that $\nu_{k-1}\mapsto\mu_x\in H_n(\R^n,\R^n\sm\{x\})$ for all $x\in V_{k-1}$ (note $\nu_1=\mu_1$). Then, $(\nu_{k-1},\mu_k)\mapsto0$ under the second map in our exact sequence, so is the image of a unique $\nu_k\in H_n(\R^n,\R^n\sm V_k)$.

The upshot is that Mayer-Vietoris allows us to glue our original $\mu_i$'s into one $\nu:=\nu_N\in H_n(\R^n,\R^n\sm V_N)$ Since $K\subset V_N$ by construction, we can let $\mu_K$ be the image of $\nu$ under $H_n(\R^n,\R^n\sm V_N)\to H_n(\R^n,\R^n\sm K)$.

Comment: I think that calling $\mu U_x$ generators is misleading. How do we know that $H_n(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n\setminus U_x)$ is a cylic group? However, with the definition of orientation I'm using this quibble shouldn't be a probelm.

Comment: I didn't explicitly say this, but you can make it cyclic if you choose $U_x$ to be reasonable (I think convex and bounded is enough). By the LES of the pair, we know $H_n(\mathbb R^n,\mathbb R^n\setminus U_x)\cong H_{n-1}(\mathbb R^n\setminus U_x)$, and if $U_x$ is reasonable, then $\mathbb R^n\setminus U_x\simeq S^{n-1}$ via the deformation retraction that radially squishes everything onto a sphere enclosing $U_x$.

Comment: Okay, but where do we use that they are generators as long as we can cover $K$ with a finite number of $U_{x}$ respecting the first request you wrote?

Comment: You're right that we don't need them to be generators. Having them be generators is more of an aesthetic thing for me. In my mind, these are orientation classes of their associated subsets, but it feels weird to think of them that way if they're not generators for their group.